# DFAs that must reach a certain state at least once

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I was given this question:

> Let M = (Q,Σ, δ, q0, F) be a deterministic finite automaton. Assume that r∈Q is a state of M that is different from the start state q0.
>
> Define the language A⊆Σ* to be the language consisting of all strings that are accepted by M and cause M to enter the state r at least once.
>
> Give a precise description (the 5-tuple definition) of a deterministic finite 
>   automaton N that accepts the language A.

My question is, wouldn't it be possible to define N as (Q,Σ, δ, q0, F) with F={r}? Unless I am sorely mistaken, it should be able to meet the question's criteria shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it happened that $F \{r\}$, then that would also happen to be a DFA to which you wouldn't have to do anything to answer the question, but it doesn't cover the case where $r \notin F$.

To rephrase the question a little, imagine you have a DFA $M$ that accepts language $L$, and someone picks a random state $r\neq s_{0}$, can you construct a DFA $M'$ that accepts language $L' \subseteq L$ where $s \in L'$ if it's in $L$ and it makes $M$ use state $r$?

Note that you don't get to pick $r$, it's essentially given as part of the input.

Taking it a little beyond your question, the answer is yes, it's possible, the trick is to do something special when you reach $r$.

A slightly more direct hint:

> Make a copy of $M$'s states (including accept status), cancel the accept status of any original states, and change the transitions out of $r$ to point to the counterparts in the duplicated set.